# Excel 2016: open and close an Excel file programmatically from sharepoint

Tags: vba, excel

I have this test code that attempts to start a hidden Excel process, load an Excel file from a location ("fileToOpen"), do something with the file and then close the file and finally close the Excel process. I'm performing my test in Excel 2016.

```
Sub test()
    Dim excelapp As Object
    Dim wbk As Workbook

    Set excelapp = CreateObject("excel.Application")
    excelapp.Visible = True

    On Error GoTo error_handler

    Set wbk = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(filename:=fileToOpen, ReadOnly:=True)

    ' Do something

    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    excelapp.Quit
    Set excelapp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

error_handler:
    MsgBox "A problem occurred", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    excelapp.Quit
    Set excelapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

For some reason the Excel process stays alive after the `excelapp.Quit` when the file is loaded from SharePoint, but is killed when the file is loaded from a local drive. This also worked fine in Excel 2010, i.e. the Excel process was properly terminated.

Any help is appreciated on how to properly close the file after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    excelapp.Quit
    Set excelapp = Nothing
```

to this

```
    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.Quit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set excelapp = Nothing
```

and the

```
    error_handler:
    MsgBox "A problem occurred", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    excelapp.Quit
    Set excelapp = Nothing
```

to this

```
    error_handler:
    MsgBox "A problem occurred", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Application.Quit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set excelapp = Nothing
```

Comment: I assume you mean `excelapp.Quit` and `excelapp.DisplayAlerts = False` instead of `Application.Quit` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`? Since it's not the same Excel application I'm trying to close that I'm using to run the code with, but rather the one I created earlier in the code. 

Nevertheless, that didn't unfortunately help - the Excel process still stays alive when the file is loaded from SharePoint and is killed if the file is loaded locally.